# RequestDispatcher .forward(req, res) in Servlet doesn't have any effect

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, dispatcher

I have a problem with forwarding to a .jsp page. Let me describe my program:

In Servlet I would like to confirm something so I did .forward() to .jsp  where I have included javascript with confirm in $(document).ready(function()...

In case OK was selected I make new XMLHttpRequest() and set a parameter confirm=1 and go back to previous Servlet where a block of code which has to execute after confirmation(confirm=1) is executed as expected. But the very last line of that block which is .forward back to .jsp seems to have no effect at all.

Servlet code:

```
if("1".equals(request.getParameter("confirm"))){
  ...
   setting some request.setAttribute();
}
else{
  ...
}

RequestDispatcher  rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(...);
rd.forward(req, res);
```

Actually, I see the correct page, but it's from before confirmation I think. It should have probably been reloaded because I have to take some attributes from request and display some things with jquery, depending  on those attributes values.

So what do you think is the cause for .forward() not having effect? Can I force the page somehow to reload?

EDIT: The first time Servlet code is executed(else case) .forward() call works fine. But next time it does nothing, no matter which page I try to forward to. Just like I would have no forward call at all. Strange. I really hope somebody has an explanation for this.

EDIT2: It's not forward problem I guess. If I do system.out.print of needed attributes I get correct values. But why is page not reloading? Even if I forward to different .jsp I still see the previous one.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29

Comment: Like I said, it's probably not forward causing problems. Or is it? How can I solve this?

Comment: provide code which makes AJAX Servlet call

Comment: I solved my problem with JSON, so I got needed attributes directly to javascript.

Comment: Better provide solution here and mark the question as close. It would be helpful to others in future.

Comment: You seem to completely misunderstand how ajax works and is supposed to work. The code which you've there is designed for "normal" (synchronous) requests, not for ajax requests. I'd suggest to invest some more time in learning what ajax exactly is.

Comment: I won't say I know everything about ajax but enough for this case I think. The Servlet code I have provided can "execute in two ways" based on a parameter 'confirm'. If it executes if case, then it won't even come to the forward call. There I did JASONObject and write it out. That's what I get in javascript from ajax call. In else case it executes "normally" including forward call which sends you to .jsp and that ajax call which is in $(document).ready(function(){...}); Please tell me if there is any bad practice in my precedure. I would gladly learn something new. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really managed to solve my problem with .jsp page not loading. I actually only needed to pass some attributes from Servlete to javascript so I used jQuery ajax call for PrintWriter so I got those attributes as a key:value pairs in javascript function. Then I simply used javascript to set those values to some spans.

Answer (score 0):

in confirm case,
are you sure you go to the end, and call the forward ?

may be you get a null pointer or something like this.

Try to add system.out.println() or run in a debug mode.

Comment: I tried debugging it but it seems like everything is executetd correctly except that forward.

Comment: I guess problem is not in forward after all. I added some system.out.print of attributes in .jsp and it has correct values. But why doesn't page reload?

Comment: Even if I forward to different page I still see the same .jsp.

Comment: do you have servletFilters ? or some url-rewriting ?

Comment: I'm not very experienced yet and I don't really know what this is. So probably not. How can I check it? What should I do if I have that?

Comment: check in web.xml, search 'filter' if found, comment and try again !

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me please where do I find web.xml?

Comment: you should find it in your WEB-INF project's webcontent or war subdirectory

Comment: it's not in WEB_INF. probably that's not the problem.